# Creating a PHP Composer installer to extract to multiple directories

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it possible to create a custom PHP Composer installer that places code in multiple different directories?  I would like to link to a repository that is setup like this:

/trunk

- /public
- /library
- /content

and composer extract that to

/myproject/public

/myproject/library

/myproject/content

Is that possible?  I know I need a custom installer to do this, but I'm not exactly sure how to setup the installer to export code from the repo and put it in multiple different directories.

Comment: Maybe you should use composer/installers instead of creating your own one? http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md

Comment: @Ziumin that works for installing it to a single directory, not really to multiple different directories.

Comment: The way I see it, trunk is your package, so if you install the package in /myproject it'll unpack those three dirs in there and all is well. The question is whether /myproject is a project made of that trunk, or if you'd want to install whatever is in trunk as a dependency of another project, yet place stuff in public/library/content. If the latter, you can't really do that without a custom installer, then again it's generally a bad idea to do it IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom installer which takes care of installing your packages into these directories. You indicate which custom installer is to be used using the "type" attribute on a package. Custom installers allow you to run any PHP code after downloading a package, so you can do anything there you can think of, in particular move different files to different places. For further details on creating a custom installer please see http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md

In general though I agree with what people commented on your question, you really should not do this to begin with. Try and restructure your project so you do not need this functionality and you will save yourself a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah I decided to go a different direction, using phing to do what i needed to do while letting composer handle dependency packages.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If still a case consider testing my library (based on a plugin by `mnsami`):

https://github.com/ideaconnect/composer-custom-directory

Allows custom paths:

```
"extra":{
    "installer-paths":{
      "./monolog/": ["monolog/monolog"]
}
```

and even dynamic name replacements:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "./packages/{$name}": ["sourcepackage/package_A","sourcepackage/package_B","sourcepackage/package_B"]
    }
},
```

with flags chain:

Currently supprted flags are:

```
F - capitalizes first letter.
P - changes all entries of a _ or - followed by a character to only that character, capitalized.
```